# getting progress information from an external .net library

Tags: c#, tracking, progress

I have a line of code that will take anywhere between 10-50 minutes to do its task which is an analysis thing. The line that is taking this long is housed in a thread however there is no callback implemented in that managed library hence I can't let the user know where we are in parsing this file.

Is there any way to delve deeper into a library by using reflection? I know that didn't sound right as reflection gives you information about the libraries types and code but does it do anything useful during runtime about external libraries? I hope the question was clear.

Thanks,

Comment: If the library does not report its progress what you want is unlikely to be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without callbacks you're probably going to be stuck estimating the time left based on some other observable side effect.

Would it be valid to track the time taken for previous runs and estimate progress based on that?

If the output is to something external like a file/db could you inspect that?

If the output is something in memory you could inspect the object in another thread if you created it or use some "unsafe" code to inspect the memory if you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.reflector.net/ to see what the code in the library actually does, but unless you find any callback hooks, then there's not much else.